# "##" in printk, what does ## mean

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

```
#define ext4_debug(f, a...)                     \
    do {                                \
        printk(KERN_DEBUG "EXT4-fs DEBUG (%s, %d): %s:",    \
            __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__);          \
        printk(KERN_DEBUG f, ## a);             \
    } while (0)
```

what I dont understand is this

```
printk(KERN_DEBUG f, ## a);
```

Could anybody help me to understand what is ## in this line?
thank you

Comment: @Insilico that's incorrect man, the question asked is different. Its regarding the preprocessor directive '##' for variadic macros, and notice you're only having `##a`, and not `g##a`.

Comment: Aniket is right, this is not a duplicate, because the `##` means something different in this context than in the context given in that question. Everyone voting to close as a duplicate: please read more carefully before doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is there to make the variadic macro (macro which can take multiple arguments) work if you pass in 0 arguments.

From the [Variadic Macros section](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html#Variadic%20Macros) in the GCC manual:

> Second, the ## token paste operator has a special meaning when placed between a comma and a variable argument. If you write
>
> ```
> #define eprintf(format, ...) fprintf (stderr, format, ##__VA_ARGS__)
> ```
>
> and the variable argument is left out when the `eprintf` macro is used, then the comma before the ## will be deleted. This does not happen if you pass an empty argument, nor does it happen if the token preceding ## is anything other than a comma.
>
> ```
> eprintf ("success!\n")
>      ==> fprintf(stderr, "success!\n");
> ```

If you did not use this, then that would expand to `frpintf(stderr, "success!\n",)`, which is a syntax error.

Comment: precisely i have been telling people that it isnt the token paster

Comment: please cast a reopen vote, this question isn't a duplicate, and was closed by some people unknowingly. This question is subtly different and original

Comment: @Aniket I have cast a reopen vote; I suspect you and I have done so. Thanks for correcting people here; it is frustrating when everyone jumps on the wrong answer or wrong voting decision too quickly.

Answer (score 3):

Its a token for variadic macros(macros with multiple, variable arguments). Its gcc specific directive that allows 0 or more arguments as an input to, after `f` in `ext4_debug()`. Which means, `f` argument is mandatory, `a` may or maynot exist.

This is same as `printf(const char *fmt,...)` where, `fmt` is mandatory, other arguments are optional and dependent on the `fmt`. See the last statement in this doc: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html